# How can I aggregate values for only the entries that are shown after a filter is applied in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am trying out the Sample Superstore dataset from the Tableau tutorial. I created a user-configurable filter that shows the top X orders based on Profit. I have done this by creating a filter parameter (with possible values: from top 1-200 entries) and a calculated field:

`RANK_UNIQUE(SUM([Profit])) <= [Top X Orders (Profit)]`

This seems to work as expected. Now I want to compute various aggregations that take into account the filtered entries only. For example, I would like to calculate the count of orders per region or maybe profit per region (again for only the filtered entries, not the full dataset).

I have tried quite a few things, like LOD calculations, but I usually get a 'cannot combine aggregate with non-aggregate expression in an IF statement', when trying to only include the filtered entries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Drag `[Top X Orders(Profit)]` to your filter pane and set it to *True* or *Use All*.

It should dynamically update if your parameter drives it.